# What does 'Inside tunnel IPv4 CIDR' in VPN Site to Site Options mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I'm configuring a VPN Site to Site in AWS and I would like to understand some Tunnel Options.

What does Inside tunnel IPV4 CIDR means ? I need to allow this range in some place ? And there's some impact if my subnet has higher IP range than this tunnel CIDR ? For example if my lambda’s subnet are /21 and this inside IPV4 CIDR tunnel is /30 ?

What should the security groups of the other account allow ? The outside IP address ?

Answer (score 0):

To understand tunnel addressing you need to understand the difference between route-based tunnels and policy-based tunnels.  Amazon uses route-based tunnels, which means that there is a virtual interface at either end of the tunnel.  The "inside tunnel ipv4 cidr" is the address space used by that tunnel interface.